# Any thoughts on this LeakyCanary report related to Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

```
D/LeakCanary: │ GC Root: Thread object
D/LeakCanary: │
D/LeakCanary: ├─ android.os.HandlerThread instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (PathClassLoader↓ is not leaking)
D/LeakCanary: │    Thread name: 'plumber-android-leaks'
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ Thread.contextClassLoader
D/LeakCanary: ├─ dalvik.system.PathClassLoader instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (SnapshotKt↓ is not leaking and A ClassLoader is never leaking)
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ ClassLoader.runtimeInternalObjects
D/LeakCanary: ├─ java.lang.Object[] array
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (SnapshotKt↓ is not leaking)
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ Object[213]
D/LeakCanary: ├─ androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotKt class
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (Recomposer↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ static SnapshotKt.applyObservers
D/LeakCanary: ├─ java.util.ArrayList instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (Recomposer↓ is not leaking)
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ ArrayList[2]
D/LeakCanary: ├─ androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$recompositionRunner$2$unregisterApplyObserver$1 instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (Recomposer↓ is not leaking)
D/LeakCanary: │    Anonymous subclass of kotlin.jvm.internal.Lambda
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ Recomposer$recompositionRunner$2$unregisterApplyObserver$1.this$0
D/LeakCanary: ├─ androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (Recomposer is in state PendingWork)
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ Recomposer.snapshotInvalidations
D/LeakCanary: │                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D/LeakCanary: ├─ java.util.LinkedHashSet instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 334.1 kB in 7548 objects
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ LinkedHashSet[element()]
D/LeakCanary: │                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
D/LeakCanary: ├─ androidx.compose.runtime.ParcelableSnapshotMutableState instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 72 B in 4 objects
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ SnapshotMutableStateImpl.next
D/LeakCanary: │                               ~~~~
D/LeakCanary: ├─ androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotMutableStateImpl$StateStateRecord instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 56 B in 3 objects
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ SnapshotMutableStateImpl$StateStateRecord.value
D/LeakCanary: │                                                ~~~~~
D/LeakCanary: ├─ androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView$ViewTreeOwners instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 16 B in 1 objects
D/LeakCanary: │    lifecycleOwner instance of ac.mdiq.mliq.elements.PEActivity with mDestroyed = true
D/LeakCanary: │    savedStateRegistryOwner instance of ac.mdiq.mliq.elements.PEActivity with mDestroyed = true
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ AndroidComposeView$ViewTreeOwners.lifecycleOwner
D/LeakCanary: │                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D/LeakCanary: ╰→ ac.mdiq.mliq.elements.PEActivity instance
D/LeakCanary: ​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because ac.mdiq.mliq.elements.PEActivity received
D/LeakCanary: ​     Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
D/LeakCanary: ​     Retaining 39.3 kB in 763 objects
D/LeakCanary: ​     key = e1091306-ead4-451a-b24c-58f91dde885c
D/LeakCanary: ​     watchDurationMillis = 5519
D/LeakCanary: ​     retainedDurationMillis = 512
D/LeakCanary: ​     mApplication instance of ac.mdiq.mliq.general.Application
D/LeakCanary: ​     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper
D/LeakCanary: ====================================
```

Any thoughts on how to clear it out?